# How to get courses in one and only one undergrad degree?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Data:

```
Programs  
- degree (name)  
- Course (course list)  

Degrees  
- code (unique identifier)  
- name  
- type (either postgrad or undergrad)  

Course  
- code (unique identifier)   
- name
```

How would I find the courses included in one and only one undergrad degree program using same data as above?

Comment: why are you calling it `Biology` in 1 table and `Bio 1` in another table? it cannot be joined this way.

Answer (score 0):

Like I wrote in the comment, you are joining `programs.course = courses.name` but `biology` is not written the same in both tables.

Once that's fixed I would write the query as follows:

```
select c.code from programs p
join degrees d on p.degree = d.code
join course c on p.course = c.name  
where d.type = 'UG'
group by c.code 
having count(degree) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want courses that are in exactly one UG degree and no PG, then:

```
select p.course
from programs p join
     degrees d
     on p.degree = d.code
group by p.course
having count(*) = 1 and min(d.type) = 'UG';
```